# Is there any tool available to automate iOS default (Email) app?

Tags: ios, calabash, appium

I have explored couple of tools like Appium, KIF: for these tools we need to own the app (to enable Automation Instrument) to automate. And also tried with .IPA files available on the internet (Gmail email client) on iOS simulator, not got any success yet.

I have a requirement to automate iOS' default Email app, is there any tool/approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your can give xcode(iOS emulator) a try and try to write a script to execute the emulator automatically.

Addendum:
I do not have a hands on experience of it but once you have your app/website running in xcode emulator you can write test scripts using the IPhoneDriver plugin of selenium webdriver and run your tests!

I suppose this link below can give you some idea of using iPhone driver -
seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/android-and-ios-support

Comment: Could you expand on how xcode could potentially solve this problem? Otherwise, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know some possible ways, but I think they are a bit far fetched for a maintainable test setup. Might get you going though.

**VNC**:

1. Jailbreak an iPhone/iPad
2. Install VNC server software
3. Use a test framework like [T-Plan Robot](http://www.t-plan.com/robot/) to run tests against the device over VNC

There is also a older open-source T-Plan robot version at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplanrobot/

Seems that you do **not have to jailbreak** if you use the iOS mirror feature: http://www.t-plan.com/robot/docs/latest/scripting/ios.html

**Emulator**:

You can use Sikuli to test against a local emulator: http://www.sikuli.org/